# What do the error messages from renderd mean?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, rendering, postgis-2.2, mod-tile

I'm pre-rendering a small section of a map for offline use, and I'm getting errors from the output of render_list.  I've set up a postgreSQL database with postGIS, and I'm using Mod Tile/Renderd to serve tiles.

The command itself returns zero, and the metaimages appear to have been created, but I'm still seeing cryptic error messages on stdout.

For example, if I run this command:

```
render_list -z 20 -Z 20 -a -x 66 -X 71 -y 94 -Y 99 -n 8
```

I would get this output:

```
Rendering all tiles for zoom 20 from (66, 94) to (71, 99)
Waiting for rendering threads to finish
rendering failed with command 0, pausing.
```

Are these error messages benign?  I can't find any documentation on what the codes mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/blob/master/src/render_submit_queue.c (in the mod_tile source), tile rendering requests are captured by the render_submit_queue, wrapped in a protocol struct defined in **protocol.h**.

The commands are encoded as an enumeration therein:

`enum protoCmd { cmdIgnore, cmdRender, cmdDirty, cmdDone, cmdNotDone, cmdRenderPrio, cmdRenderBulk, cmdRenderLow };`

Within various functions defined in **request_queue.c**, the common thread among uses of command 0 (cmdIgnore) is a submitted request which is already enqueued in some fashion.

Since the command from the original post was otherwise successful, I assume that somewhere along the line, a duplicate request was made which triggered the "failed with command 0" message.  The error is benign in this case.

There aren't any comments for other commands, but searching the mod_tile repository for uses of each reveals enough about each to determine what they might mean when encountered.

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted above is the output from "render_list".  "renderd" will be sending output to wherever you've told it to go.  https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-16-04-2-lts/ contains information about how to see information in the foreground ("Running renderd for the first time") and sending it to syslog ("Running renderd in the background").

However, it's also worth checking the x, X, y and Y parameters that you're using.  Are they definitely correct for the data that you want rendered at zoom 20?

Comment: The parameters are valid as I understand them: natural number from 0 to 2^(zoom-1).

Comment: I was referring to the output from renderd to stdout, as passed to render_list when it invokes renderd.  The render_list script gathers the linux return code from renderd, and passes it along to stdout.  There does not appear to be any documentation of what the error codes indicate.  I understand that renderd outputs to the specified folder, I looked there to verify that metatiles were indeed rendered.

Comment: render_list connects to renderd via the socket that renderd uses for incoming requests.  If it can't connect you'll get an error like "socket connect failed for: /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock".
When you previously started renderd you probably ran it in the background, so its errors will probably be in "/var/log/syslog" or similar.

Note - the "render_list" that's shipped with mod_tile isn't a script, it's a program.  Are you perhaps referring to some other script?  If so, where did you get it from?

Comment: Re the validity of parameters, on an example server here "render_list -z 20 -Z 20 -a -x 66 -X 71 -y 94 -Y 99 -n 8 -m ajt" is valid (I need the "-m ajt" because I have no "default" tile style), but may not render the tiles that you actually want.  You might find https://github.com/alx77/render_list_geo.pl useful for that.

Comment: Script was a misnomer, I understand that it is not a script.  I'm using the OpenStreetMap source [here](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile).  Here's an example that fails and the exact return I'm getting:  `render_list -z 20 -Z 20 -a -x 66 -X 67 -y 94 -Y 95 -n 8` yields `debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
Rendering client
Starting 8 rendering threads
Rendering all tiles from zoom 20 to zoom 20
Rendering all tiles for zoom 20 from (66, 94) to (67, 95)
Waiting for rendering threads to finish
rendering failed with command 0, pausing.`

Comment: I'm afraid the $64,000 question is still "what error do you get from renderd"?  Where those error messages go depend on how you started it, so taking a step back, how are you running renderd?

Comment: I'm running renderd as set up with [these](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04) instructions.  As far as I can tell, the error is "command 0".  There does not appear to be a logfile specified in renderd.conf.

Comment: OK, based on that I'd expect renderd's output to go into "/var/log/syslog".  Is anything written there?